# Why does JQuery .live work with deleting dynamically added items but JQuery .on or .bind does not?

Tags: jquery

I've heard that JQuery .live has been deprecated and should not be used any more.  I've got some sample code below that I've written where I have a button, with an id of adddiv, which appends a div with an id of seconddiv to an existing div with an id of firstdiv.

Within the seconddiv, I have another button, with an id of delete, that, when clicked, I want to delete the seconddiv.  The code works fine as is, but if I change the JQuery where I'm catching the click event for the delete button to use either .on or .bind, it fails to work.

Can anyone tell me how to change this to use either .on or .bind to get this to work?

HTML:

```
<div id="firstdiv">
Pre Existing Div
<input type="button" id="adddiv" value="Add Div" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

        $('#adddiv').click(function () {
            $('#firstdiv').append('<div id="seconddiv"> Click here to delete the second div: <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete Div"></div>')
        });

        $('#delete').live('click', function (e) { 
            $(this).parent('#seconddiv').remove();
        });   
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is set up like this: 
`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )`.

Basically, you need to bind it to a selector that already exists, so for this example, you could use the following selectors:

- `$(document).on()`
- `$('body').on()`
- `$('#firstdiv').on()`

---

Next, you specify what `event`:

- `$(document).on('click')`
- `$('body').on('click')`
- `$('#firstdiv').on('click')`

*NOTE:* If you want to bind multiple events, add a space between events:

`$(document).on('click mouseover')`

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uBuH7/1/

---

Then, you say which elements trigger the event:

- `$(document).on('click', '#delete')`
- `$('body').on('click', '#delete')`
- `$('#firstdiv').on('click', '#delete')`

*NOTE:* If you want to bind multiple elements, then use a comma:

`$(document).on('click', '#delete, #delete2')`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uBuH7/2/

---

Finally, you add a handler:

- `$(document).on('click', '#delete', function(){ })`
- `$('body').on('click', '#delete', function(){ })`
- `$('#firstdiv').on('click', '#delete', function(){ })`

---

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 $().ready(function () {
    $('#adddiv').click(function () {
        $('#firstdiv').append('<div id="seconddiv"> Click here to delete the second div: <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete Div"></div>')
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
        $(this).parent('#seconddiv').remove();
    });   
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uBuH7/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

        $('#adddiv').click(function () {
            $('#firstdiv').append('<div id="seconddiv"> Click here to delete the second div: <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete Div"></div>')
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#delete', function (e) { 
            $(this).parent('#seconddiv').remove();
        });   
    });
</script>
```

In the `on` event where I have put `body` as the event handler, this can be any element as long as it parents the element that you will be calling, in you case `#delete`. The further up the DOM tree you use for an event handler the further the bubbling effect will go.

One thing to keep in mind when choosing an event handler however is that you have to make sure that it will be available in the DOM, so in that case it is always safe to use `$(document)` as the event handler.

See the jQuery `on` documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things I'd like to change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Event handler to delete a second div
    var onDelete = function (e) { 
        $(this).closest('#seconddiv').remove();
    };
    // Event handler to add a second div
    var onAdd = function () {
        // create div
        var div = $('<div/>', {
           id: 'seconDiv',
           text: 'Click here to delete the second div:'
        });
        // create button
        var button = $('<input/>', {
            id: 'delete',
            type: 'button',
            value: 'Delete Div'
        });
        // wrap them together and append
        div.append(button).appendTo('#firstDiv');
    };

    // Event binding .on(event, selector, handler)
    $(document).on('click', '#addiv', onAdd);
    $(document).on('click', '#delete', onDelete);
</script>
```

1. When using `.on()`, you don't need the `$().ready()` as long as the first selector is present in the DOM when the event is bound. Thus the `$(document)` selector. Simplifies code.
2. If you use `.on()`, try to stick using it. Using both `.on('click'..)` and `.click()` is messy and confusing.
3. Mixing html and javascript is messy, so why not construct html elements the jQuery way? Saves you from horizontal scrolling when trying to figure out the attributes of an element you just created. Plus you'll have the full jQuery support at your fingertips even before you inject your element to the dom
4. Using `.closest()` instead of `.parent()` would allow minor html changes without breaking the code.
5. And of course using `.on()` instead of the deprecated `.live()` is a good idea.
6. I also like to separate the event binding and handling. Having all event binders closely stacked together, makes it easier to figure out what events are present on the document.